# Docker doesn't work after installed on Ubuntu 14 based on official tutorial

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am using official Ubuntu 14
[image]

I am following [this](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu) official document to install docker.

After install, docker exists on the server, but it just doesn't work.

```
docker ps 
// or 
docker run hello-world
```

All return the same error

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.[image]

I am really new to docker, what is going wrong? How to run docker deamon?

Result of "sudo service docker status" command:[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you logout/login and try again?

Comment: @hurturk I reboot the server, same error message. How to run docker as deamon?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon  This page mentioned my error message, but no clue to fix it.

Comment: Maybe usermod failed, you can add it manually `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` then logout/login to the server and see if it works. That is what docker installation does usually.

Comment: @hurturk tried your command, same error msg

Comment: Have you tried adding `sudo` to the command you are trying? At least that can prove it is user related. `sudo docker ps`

Comment: yes, same error msg, since the "deamon" is not running.

Comment: @hurturk do you know how to use "update-rc.d" to run the deamon?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 installation usually sets up everything, see if it actually works by `sudo service docker status` command. Perhaps `sudo service docker start` to start, then you can add that to your question to point the next error.

Comment: Updated the result in question, but "docker ps" still got the same error msg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145824/discussion-between-nicolas-s-xu-and-hurturk).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

I see you using the 'sudo' command when starting/stopping/checking the Docker service, but not when issuing the 'docker' commands.  Try using: `sudo docker <command>`

It's likely due to the user you are issuing the docker commands with not being apart of the Docker-associated group.

Try: `cat /etc/group | grep docker`

This should spit back the docker group that exists...on my CentOS 7 the group is called 'dockerroot'

So, I add myself to the 'dockerroot' group: `sudo usermod -aG dockerroot username`

Obviously, replace `username` with your actual username.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14, just tried your way. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your user to `docker`group, then, your user isn't able to user Docker daemon. To fix this, you have two options.

**Option 1)** Add your user to `docker` group with the following command:

`sudo usermod -aG docker your_user`

**Option 2)** Execute your `docker` commands using `sudo`

Be aware that add your user to `docker` group is equivalent to give full root access to your user. https://www.andreas-jung.com/contents/on-docker-security-docker-group-considered-harmful